# Using type 1 fonts without altering document font

Tags: fonts, type1

I am using Texmaker in Windows and need to create a document with type 1 fonts only. When using:

```
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I seem to still be using type 3 fonts, according to the website where I want to submit the document to. The output looks like this:
[image: no lmodern]

Adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` makes the font completely different and bigger (see below), implying that my document no longer fits the required number of pages. (In the example shown in the image below, the same text takes up 12 lines instead of 11, as in the picture above.)
[image: with lmodern]

Can anyone help me set up my document so that I use T1 fonts that do not make my text take up more pages?

Many thanks,
Marta

End of log file (without lmodern):

{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc}

> 

Comment: Compile your document with pdflatex. Then check the end of the log-file: which fonts there have the extension .pk?

Comment: I haven't even read the question, but it's recommended that you provide us witha a compilable example (from `\documentclass{…}` to `\end{document}`).

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer. Searching for .pk in the log file gives no results in either version.

Comment: With `\usepackage{times}` (which is obsolete, by the way), you surely get Type1 fonts, unless you're using a really old TeX system.

Comment: You are using a Times clone (narrow width), so it's not surprising that Latin Modern makes the text too big. Did you load `lmodern` before `times` (which itself would be better done using `mathptmx`)? If you load `lmodern` first then a Times clone, the latter will be used for most glyphs.

Comment: Show your log file (and be sure to compile with pdflatex! That means pdf output!).

Comment: Thanks, @JosephWright. That sorted out the abnormal size with lmodern, but the website I am trying to submit the document to still says I am using type 3 fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: {C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}{
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathsy.enc}{C:/Program Files/
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/
enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathex.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontnam
e/8r.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmex10.pfb><C:/Prog
ram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi10.pfb>

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: <C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 
2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi5.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pu
blic/lm/lmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi8.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/ty
pe1/public/lm/lmr7.pfb

Comment: A common source for Type 3 fonts with font encoding `T1` is that the TeX distribution package (MiKTeX, TeX Live) `cm-super` is not installed. Install it, if this is the case. Then check the fonts of the PDF file (e.g. command `pdffonts` or the font information of AR, ...).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to show the fonts with lmodern. Compile your original document. Also you should add the information to your question not in the comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks. Added as per request.

Comment: I wrote "show the log-file" not "show end of log-file". Also first do as Heiko wrote: install the cm-super package.

Comment: I don't know how to install packages in Miktex in Windows... I will try to figure that out and get back to you.

Comment: Hi. I have donwloaded and followed this instructions of the cm-super package available online and added \usepackage{type1ec} to the document. The website still complains I am using type 3 fonts. Happy to upload the log file - please let me know how to do that other than uploading a screenshot of the log.

Comment: Hi. Have managed to solve the problem. (It turns out the website was using XeLateX rather than PdfLaTeX, which caused the problems.) It would have been useful to have known that the cm-super package can be installed in Windows using the install on the fly option if \usepackage{type1ec}. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You don't need to add \usepackage{type1ec} to your document. cm-super will also work without it. Also you should check the manual of miktex: it has a package manager.